# How to use Picasso to load cached image when open the app without internet

Tags: android, picasso

I am using Picasso to load image coming from URL. This app is usable in Offline mode too.

In online mode, Picasso fetch the user profile image from server and display it, but when user opens the app in offline mode it shows the placeholder image. But how can I show the same cached image in offline mode too?

this is the code I am using:-

```
Picasso picasso = new Picasso.Builder(context)
            .downloader(new OkHttp3Downloader(client))
            .loggingEnabled(true)
            .build();
    picasso.load(imgUrl).networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.OFFLINE).fit().centerCrop().into(imageView, new com.squareup.picasso.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess() {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Succcess", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Failure", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            picasso.load(imgUrl).placeholder(placeHolderId).error(placeHolderId).fit().centerCrop().into(imageView);
        }
    });
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you able to use glide instead of picasso ? Glide caches images by default.

Comment: Use [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) instead!

Comment: @rogalz thanks for your reply, let me check with that.

Comment: @rogalz I have chcked but Glide doesnot perform well evrytime (in my case). 
I am sending NONCE and Authorization Bearer to fetch image, and glide gives error in handling all this.